# c++ jemalloc malloc large fix size (64K, 128K) memory takes more than 300us

Tags: c++, jemalloc

I use jemalloc for memory allocation, a lot of threads allocate small or large objects concurrently, and I monitor two large object(64K, 128K) and find that:  every 2 or 3 seconds, an 64K or 128K allocation takes about more than 300us. How to fix this problem.

Comment: Random guess: (since you're not giving us any other information) Does this stall coincide with a call to `mmap` or `sbrk`?

Comment: You can additionally compare jemalloc with alternatives, such as glibc, tcmalloc, tbbmalloc. At least to find out whether the problem is jemalloc-related.

Comment: Generally, if deallocations are performed by the same threads as corresponding allocations, thread-local memory pools may help. Here is an article about the whole problem, however, it requires subscription: https://doi.org/10.1109/TPDS.2019.2960514.

Comment: An object pool may help the unnecessary deallocation and reallocatoin.

Comment: thanks for your help, I find a solution to write my own allocator for fix big size, it is much better than the default jemalloc.